# Infopath 2010 File Attachment control's delete not working

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, office-web-apps

I have a List that is customized using Infopath form. In that list edit form I have a File Attachment control and using it I am able to attach the documents, but the "delete" icon next to each attachment when clicked prompts with a dialog box requesting confirmation of the attachment deletion.

When I click ok, the attachment is removed, then if I refresh the page or click on the "Submit" button the attachments still remains.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a Microsoft Fix for this issue here: [SharePoint Server 2010 hotfix package](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2598380)